# Can I use "they" with "OP"?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, personal-pronouns

Looking at the NOAD, I read that using *they* as pronoun to mean a person of either sex is acceptable in those contexts where it follows an indefinite pronoun such *as anyone*, *no one*, *someone*, or *a person*.

Can I use *they* with *OP*?

My thought is that the OP could ask a question about something a group of people is doing / trying to do, and I could use *they* to refer to the supposed group of people. Would this be an acceptable reason to use *they* when referring to *OP*?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If the OP is talking about a group of people, *they*, is the perfect pronoun to use. The group contains people, people is plural, thus the pronoun is "they". If however you wanted to start a sentence with "Every OP.... then you could use "they" and "their" so as to avoid "he or she" and "his or her" clauses.

Comment: For example, is "the OP doesn't understand what they should do" acceptable? The NOAD talks of "indefinite pronouns," which doesn't include _OP_, as far as I understand.

Comment: O.K, that example is perfectly fine. Nothing wrong there :) Sometimes though it's clear from the username (and the avatar) that the person is either a female or a male *ahem!*.

Comment: It's not always the case. _kiamlaluno_ comes from Esperanto, where the final _o_ doesn't mean "it's male." Without me telling you my gender, are you sure to know it? Does "when the moon" (the translation of _kiam la luno_) tells you I am female? `o.0`

Comment: I said sometimes, my name is female and you see my face on the avatar. Fumblefingers, has to be a man for example. There's no doubt in my mind. I could never use "they" with FF. I've always imagined you to be a man, judging by your profile and the type of questions and answers you give. I could be wrong. But I doubt it :P

Comment: I think singular *they* can refer back to *the OP* even if you know whether they're male or female.  But *they* referring back to *Mari-Lou A* would be odd.  In other words, I believe that whether *they* is acceptable has more to do with the choice of words than to whether the gender of the referent is known.

Comment: Snailboat makes a very valid point; if you're using the term, OP, to address any user then you can follow with *they* as shown by Wendikidd's examples. I'm not wild about the acronym, OP, myself it sounds very impersonal but it's certainly an improvement on usernames which are a series of numbers. If I were talking about user *246810* and whether their contribution was correct, I would definitely use "they" as the pronoun.

Comment: _[see also](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120393/what-is-the-proper-way-to-refer-to-the-original-poster-op)_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this. There are some people who don't like it, and say you should always use *he/she* instead of *they* and *his/her* instead of *theirs*. But presuming you choose not to do that (which  I don't!) using *they* and *their* is perfectly fine. You will always be understood, and most people won't even blink. So an exchange like this in comments on an answer would be just fine:

> Your answer is correct, but the OP only asked about A. I don't think you needed to explain B and C. **- Person 1, 10 mins ago**
>
> @Person1 I understand that, I was just trying to help *them*. The OP mentioned that *they* were working on a project related to D, which concerns B and C. I thought *their* project might be improved if they were aware of how B and C relate to A. **- you, just now**

All three of those uses (*they*, *them*, and *their*) are perfectly acceptable.